# Examples where $(a+b+\cdots)^2 = (a^2+b^2+\cdots)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Consider the two infinite series

$$
    \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{8}} = 1 + \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{11} - \cdots
$$
and
$$
    \frac{\pi^2}{8} = 1 + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{5^2} + \frac{1}{7^2} + \frac{1}{9^2} + \frac{1}{11^2} + \cdots
$$

(Notice that the first series has signs that go two-by-two rather than every-other.)

Squaring the first equality also gives $\pi^2/8$ and so these two, when put together, satisfy the 'highschooler's dream' for squaring a sum: just square each term and sum,
$$
    (a + b + c + \cdots)^2 = (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + \cdots)
$$
with nothing like $2ab + 2ac + 2bc + \cdots$ needed.

A trivial example of this would be
$$
    (a + 0)^2 = a^2 + 2a0 + 0^2 = a^2 + 0^2
$$
but it only succeeds because one addend is zero.

My questions are

- Are there any other simple nontrivial examples?  <strike>I believe any other nontrivial example must be an infinite sum.</strike> edit: John Omielan provides the simple finite example $(1+1-\frac{1}{2})^2 = 1^2 + 1^2 + \frac{1}{2^2}$.
- Is there an "obvious" demonstration that the above sum (other than the direct evaluation) satisfies the highschooler's dream?  Put another way, is there a simple demonstration that the infinite sum of "cross terms" vanishes?

Comment: A fairly simple, what I consider to be non-trivial, finite example is $\left(1 + 1 - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = 1^2 + 1^2 + \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{9}{4}$.

Comment: Excellent!  I updated the question with your example.

Comment: An example with $4$ summands is $[2, 5, 6, -4]$

Comment: @evanb By multiplying each term by $2$, a slightly simpler example that used only integers would have been $(2 + 2 - 1)^2 = 2^2 + 2^2 + (-1)^2 = 9$. In general, as Peter's comment suggests, there are examples with any number of summands of integers, with this requiring at a minimum that at least one integer is positive and one is negative.

Comment: Sure, it's clear that once you find any example you can multiply by a common constant.

Comment: So we can concentrate on the second part which is anyway much more interesting. I am not an expert in sich manipulations, but I guess some telescoping will do the job.

Comment: In fact, we can find an example with every number (greater than $2$) of summands : $a$ copies of $2$ followed by $1-a$ does the job since $(2a+1-a)^2=(a+1)^2=(1-a)^2+4a$

Comment: It is a bit strange that when viewed as "a copies of 2" this makes sense and is correct, as one then gets "a many copies of 4" on the right. However, viewed as a direct example attempt with just the three-term sub being squared, it fails for a>1 because the direct result should have 4a^2 in this. I quote:  "In fact, we can find an example with every number (greater than 2) of summands : a copies of 2 followed by 1-a does the job since (2a+1-a)2=(a+1)2=(1-a)2+4a –  Peter  Mar 24 at 10:48"  THAT IS, JUST VIEWED AS A SINGLE EQUATION, YES, THE 1-a IS BEING SQUARED, BUT NOT THE 2a!

Answer (score 21):

There are arbitrary length examples with real numbers. Moreover, you can take almost arbitrary first $k-1$ numbers $a_1$, $a_2$, ... , $a_{k-1}$ and always exists $a_k$ such that $$(a_1+a_2+...+a_{k-1}+a_k)^2=a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_{k-1}^2+a_k^2$$

Let's prove it: Mark partial sums as $a_1 +...+a_{k-1}=A \neq 0$ and $a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_{k-1}^2=B$. Then $a_k$ must satisfy $$(A+a_k)^2=B+a_k^2$$

$$A^2+2Aa_k+a_k^2=B+a_k^2 \Rightarrow 2Aa_k=B-A^2 \Rightarrow a_k=\frac{B-A^2}{2A}$$

The only limitation put on $a_1$, ..., $a_{k-1}$ for existence of $a_k$ is that $A\neq 0$.

Comment: For clarity. Let's take arbitrary $k$ and $a_i$: $k=4$, $a_1=4$, $a_2=5$, $a_3=7$. Then $A=4+5+7=16$, $B=16+25+49=90$, $a_4=\frac{B-A^2}{2A}=\frac{90-256}{32}=-83/16$. Check: $(4+5+7+(-83/16))^2=(173/16)^2=29929/256$, $16+25+49+(-83/16)^2=29929/256$. OK.

Comment: More strictly: $A=0$ does not imply $B=0$ (see previous comment). Case $A=0$, $B\neq 0$ has no solution $a_k$ because of contradiction. Case $A=0$, $B=0$ is trivial: solution $a_k$ is any real number. That's why I've put limitation $A\neq 0$ in my answer.

Comment: Yes, but in the dream $B=A^2$ and so $a_k=0$. Not?

Comment: Han de Brujin: Of course, if you have example with $B=A^2$ you can use only $a_k=0$. The answer also covers this case. This answer is not induction or recursive procedure, it's about what I need to add to make $(A+a_k)^2=B+a_k^2$.

Answer (score 6):

one example would be, if $\omega$ is a complex cube root of unity, then

$$(1+\omega+\omega^2)^2=1+\omega^2+\omega^4$$

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I feel that although this one looks nice, it is not as profound as it looks, given the fact that $1+\omega+\omega^2=0$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis then what about $(1+\omega+\omega^2+1)^2=1+\omega^2+\omega^4+1^2$

Answer (score 6):

It may qualify as trivial, but note that there are infinitely many such series.

Consider a divergent series with positive decreasing terms $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n$, such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n^2$ is convergent to $L$, then it's a known theorem that we can change the signs of $u_n$ so as to get a series convergent to any given real number. Just pick $\sqrt{L}$.

That is, there exist $\sigma_n\in\{+1,-1\}$ such that $\sqrt{L}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sigma_nu_n$ while $L=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sigma_nu_n)^2$.

---

The idea of the proof of the aforementioned theorem, assuming $x>0$ (otherwise start with negative terms): sum $u_n$ until you get a value greater than $x$, call it $v_1$. Then sum $-u_n$ until you get a value smaller than $x$, call the sum of the new terms $v_2$, and continue this process to define $v_k$ for all $k$. Then $\sum_k v_k$ is alternating and convergent to $x$.

Comment: Wow, wonderful!  Applied to my original example, the point is that $\sum_{k} (2k+1)^{-1}$ diverges while $L=\sum_{k} (2k+1)^{-2}$ converges.  It just so happens that a "simple" choice of signs (alternating 2-by-2) gives the $\sqrt{L}$ value.

Answer (score 2):

The first term
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {a_1  + a_2  +  \cdots  + a_n } \right)^2  = R^2 \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left( {{{a_1 } \over R} + {{a_2 } \over R} +  \cdots
  + {{a_n } \over R}} \right)^2  - 1 = 0\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  & \left( {\left( {b_1  + b_2  +  \cdots  + b_n } \right) + 1} \right) \cdot
 \left( {\left( {b_1  + b_2  +  \cdots  + b_n } \right) - 1} \right) = 0 \cr} 
$$
is the equation (in $b_k$) of two diagonal planes, symmetric wrt the  origin, with normal vector $(1,1, \ldots , 1)$,
through the point
$$
 \pm \left( {{1 \over n},{1 \over n}, \ldots ,{1 \over n}} \right)
$$
and thus each at a distance from the origin of
$$
{1 \over {\sqrt n }}
$$

The second term
$$
\eqalign{
  & a_1 ^2  + a_2 ^2  +  \cdots  + a_n ^2  = R^2 \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad b_1 ^2  + b_2 ^2  +  \cdots  + b_n ^2  = 1 \cr} 
$$
is a unitary sphere centered at the origin.

Therefore the equality
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {a_1  + a_2  +  \cdots  + a_n } \right)^2  = a_1 ^2  + a_2 ^2  +  \cdots  + a_n ^2  = R^2
 \quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad \left( {b_1  + b_2  +  \cdots  + b_n } \right)^2
  = b_1 ^2  + b_2 ^2  +  \cdots  + b_n ^2  = 1 \cr} 
$$
is satisfied whenever the points $b_k$ lie on one of the two circles resulting from the intersection,
and the points $a_k$ on any dilation of those circles, i.e. on the conic surface with vertex at the origin, axis $(1,1, \ldots , 1)$, cross-section defined by the  above circle on the unitary sphere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this may interest you or answer your question but if you play around with field different from $\mathbb{R}$, special things happens. For example working with field $\mathbb{F}$ with characteristic equal to 2 it's always true that
$$(a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2, \space \forall a,b \in \mathbb{F}$$

And if we take another finite sum $(a + b+ c+ d)^2$ in order to obtain the claim what we want is
$$2(ab + ac + ad + ...) = 0$$

and since that term is even we can choose a field with proper even characteristic and we obtain a series of examples that are non trivial.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is the same as Ivan's. However I give an alternative proof of his statement, which is too long for a comment.

> You can take almost arbitrary first $k-1$ numbers $a_1$, $a_2$, ... ,
> $a_{k-1}$ and always exists $a_k$ such that
> $$(a_1+a_2+...+a_{k-1}+a_k)^2={a_1}^2+{a_2}^2+...+{a_{k-1}}^2+{a_k}^2$$

**My Proof:**

We have:

$$ (a_1+a_2+...+a_{k-1})^2=a_1^2+a_2^2+...+{a_{k-1}}^2 \iff \sum_{1\ \leq\ i\ <\ j\ \leq\ k-1} a_i a_j = 0. $$

Now let

$$a_k = \frac{ - \left(\displaystyle\sum_{1\ \leq\ i\ <\ j\ \leq\ k-1} a_i a_j\right) } { \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} a_i}.$$

This implies:

$$ \sum_{1\ \leq\ i\ <\ j\ \leq\ k} a_i a_j = \sum_{1\ \leq\ i\ <\ j\ \leq\ k-1} a_i a_j + a_k \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} a_i = 0, $$

with the definition of $a_k$ being possible if and only if $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{k} a_i \neq 0.$